# how can I convert the if block with insertAfter and insertBefore code in ternary way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

how can I convert the below code in ternary way?

```
if(epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked')){
$("#dcolor").insertAfter("#lmodel");
}else{
$("#dcolor").insertBefore("#otherlabeldiv");
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: to get in one line rather than using 4 line

Comment: Well, but what about readability? 1 line doesn't mean it will be better. In your case, it will be just worst

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
var c = epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked');
$("#dcolor")["insert" + (c ? "After" : "Before")](c ? "#lmodel" : "#otherlabeldiv");
```

Or even a one-liner:

```
$("#dcolor")["insert" + (epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked') ? "After" : "Before")](epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked') ? "#lmodel" : "#otherlabeldiv");
```

However, that's just using the ternary operator for the sake of using the operator.

Keep your code short, but more importantly, keep your code **readable**:

```
var element = $("#dcolor");
if(epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked')){
    element.insertAfter("#lmodel");
}else{
    element.insertBefore("#otherlabeldiv");
}
```

This will save everyone involved a headache if you have to maintain your code a year from now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this transformation when you only have one expression per line

```
condition ?     // if (condition)
    expr_true   //     expr_true;
:               // else
    expr_false; //     expr_false;
```

So yours would become

```
epaper.othermakemodel.is(':checked') ?
    $("#dcolor").insertAfter("#lmodel")
:
    $("#dcolor").insertBefore("#otherlabeldiv");
```

It's not really helpful in your case, though.

Remember, the majority of whitespace has no meaning in *JavaScript*, so you could even write this on one line with `if..else`.